# why is my MongoDB.Driver package so slow in c#?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I designed a mongoDB database and i am trying to do queries on this database using a C# script. But this is very slow compared to MongoDB Compass.

using this script:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Connect to MongoDB
        var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017"; // Update with your MongoDB connection string
        var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        var databaseName = "Database"; // Update with your database name
        var collectionName = "MachineLog"; // Update with your collection name
        var database = client.GetDatabase(databaseName);
        var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collectionName);

        // Set limit of results and number of iterations
        var limit = 691200; // Update with desired limit of results
        var numIterations = 3; // Update with desired number of iterations

        // Define filter criteria
        var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("MachineId", "64355f06d1478b55c0446d7c"); // Update with your filter criteria
        //var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Empty;

        // Perform connection establishment outside of stopwatch
        collection.Find(filter).Limit(1).ToList(); // Perform a dummy query to establish the connection

        // Perform multiple iterations and calculate average time
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        long totalElapsedTime = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numIterations; i++)
        {
            // Start timing
            stopwatch.Start();

            // Perform database operation(s) here
            // Example: Query documents with limit and filter
            var documents = collection.Find(filter).Limit(limit).ToList();

            // Stop timing
            stopwatch.Stop();
            var elapsedTime = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            totalElapsedTime += elapsedTime;

            // Reset stopwatch for next iteration
            stopwatch.Reset();

            // Print elapsed time for this iteration
            Console.WriteLine($"Iteration {i + 1}: Elapsed Time: {elapsedTime} ms");
        }

        // Calculate average time
        var averageElapsedTime = totalElapsedTime / numIterations;
        Console.WriteLine($"Average Elapsed Time: {averageElapsedTime} ms");
    }
}
```

Returns:

```
Iteration 1: Elapsed Time: 6279 ms
Iteration 2: Elapsed Time: 6056 ms
Iteration 3: Elapsed Time: 6014 ms
Average Elapsed Time: 6116 ms
```

But when i do the same query in MongoDB Compass i get results in an instant.

[image]

Changing the .ToList() to ToListAsync() does not change anything. I am not sure what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to put the stopwatch around the loop and then take an average, since a stopwatch doesn't have zero overhead when setting it up?

Comment: I would argue that loading ~700k records into memory is quite fast actually. Also `ToList` can be a bit of bottleneck here due to several resizes and potential GC.  Also maybe MongoDB Compass is not actually loading them all.

Comment: @GuruStron even if i do this query that shows results in MongoDB Compass, it returns it in an instant. although it only shows 20 per page, so it might only load the first 20 and just show the total amount found as a number.

Comment: @NickdeBoer I have not worked with Mongo that much. If it have some kind of profiler - check what actual queries are executed. Also maybe there are some cursor/streaming options in mongo allowing the tool to perform lazy processing.

Comment: @Guru I think you're right about the cursor. Behind the scenes the Mongo driver sets up a cursor that loads something like 50 document sat a time by default. So when OP calls `.ToList()` it's actually looping over that cursor to build the list.

Comment: OP: Instead of calling `.ToList()`, call `.ToCursor()`, and then call the first `MoveNext()` on the cursor. I'm going to guess that that will be similar time-wise to the Compass query.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put an index on your search index, here MachineId ?

```
var indexOptions = new CreateIndexOptions();
var indexKeys = Builders<BsonDocument>.IndexKeys.Ascending("MachineId");
var indexModel = new CreateIndexModel<BsonDocument>(indexKeys, indexOptions);
string indexName = collection.Indexes.CreateOne(indexModel);
```

In this example with or without index the response time is 720 ms with no index and 89ms with an index

https://github.com/iso8859/learn-mongodb-by-example/blob/main/dotnet/02%20-%20Intermediate/IndexAndLimit.cs